# How to make print() accept the user input in same line?

Tags: python

When i  am tying to take user input in python then it is taking input in next line but I want ti to take input in same line. How to achieve that?

I am taking input like this

```
print("Enter your name:",end=" ")
```

It is showing on console as

```
Enter your name:
Ankit
```

but I want it as

```
Enter your name:Ankit
```

Comment: I just cannot understand how do you take input by `print`...

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `input` method:

```
response = input("Enter your name:")
```

(or `raw_input` for python 2)

Answer (score 0):

By using the input() method
Just type,

```
userinput = input("Enter your name: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Python 2.x`:

```
response = raw_input("Enter your name:")
```

If you are using `Python 3.x`:

```
response = input("Enter your name:")
```

**Alternate solution:**

For python 2.x:

```
print("Enter your name:"),
response = raw_input()
```

For python 3.x:

```
print("Enter your name:", end="")
response = input()
```